# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "stderr" referenced by "/lib/arm64/libxdjakey.so"

Tags: android-studio, android-11

Process: com.example.devicemanagement, PID: 8315
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "stderr" referenced by "/data/app/~~SwJhrtMqK1xjZiTWYAtz-g==/com.example.devicemanagement-Rr0pfR7HhrsGN3ToZMtIiA==/lib/arm64/libxdjakey.so"...
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
at com.example.devicemanagement.CalcAndroid.(CalcAndroid.java:6)
at com.example.devicemanagement.RegisterActivity.saveRegisterInfo(RegisterActivity.java:115)
at com.example.devicemanagement.RegisterActivity.access$500(RegisterActivity.java:15)
at com.example.devicemanagement.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:72)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Sending signal. PID: 8315 SIG: 9

I have tried many solutions but have not succeeded in solving this problem. Who can help me？
Current Compilation environment Android studio 2021.3.1.17 android-11